# Windows batch file - sorting files by modified and/or creation date into folders

Tags: windows, file, date, batch-file, directory

I'm trying to adapt existing batch files posted on StackOverflow for my task but need guidance on a particular area of Batch File syntax and commands.

The task is to sort a folder full of image files into sub-folders by creation and/or modification date (whichever is the earlier).

The below script works for the file creation date, however, where a group of files have been copied in from another folder then they all have the same creation date (but retain the earlier 'modified' date, hence why I wish to use whichever date is the earliest)

Any suggestions gratefully received.

The code I've been looking at adapting:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set RawData="C:\Users\Jernau\source_image\*.jpg"
    set ArchiveFolder="C:\Users\Jernau\source_image\organised\"
    for %%a in ("%RawData%") do (
        echo Processing %%~nxa ...
        set File=%%~fa
        for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ('wmic datafile where "name=
            '!File:\=\\!'" get 'CreationDate' /format:csv ^| find /i  
            "%ComputerName%"') do (set CreationDate=%%b)
        echo %%~nxa: !CreationDate!
        set cYear=!CreationDate:~0,4!
        set cMonth=!CreationDate:~4,2!
        set cDay=!CreationDate:~6,2!
        set TimeStamp=!cYear!-!cMonth!-!cDay!
        if not exist "%ArchiveFolder%\!TimeStamp!" (
            md "%ArchiveFolder%\!TimeStamp!"
        )
        move "!File!" "%ArchiveFolder%\!TimeStamp!"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the (.VBS) script I ended up with. Modified from code found elsewhere, this creates sub-folders for all photos in the target folder by date the photo was taken. It's not perfect, but for processing my camera outputs it does the job very well.

```vbs
folderName = "C:\photos to sort into folder\"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(folderName)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderName)
Set fc = f.Files

For Each fs In fc
   If lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(fs)) = "jpg" Then

      Set objFolderItem =  objFolder.ParseName(fs.Name)
      strValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 12)

      If strValue <> "" Then

'Local time settings cause problems with DatePart, so manually split and set strValue to a Date object
strValue = CDate(right(left(strValue,13),4) & "-" & right(left(strValue,7),2) & "-" & right(left(strValue,3),2))

          newYY = DatePart("yyyy", strValue)
          newMM = DatePart("m", strValue)
          If newMM < 10 Then newMM = "0" & newMM
          newDD = DatePart("d", strValue)
            If newDD < 10 Then newDD = "0" & newDD
            newFolder = folderName  & newYY & "-" & newMM & "-" & newDD    'check for valid drive and path

                If Not fso.FolderExists(newFolder) Then 
                fso.CreateFolder(newFolder)
                End If

'               fso.CopyFile fs.Path, newFolder & "\"
                fso.MoveFile fs.Path, newFolder & "\"
        End If 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes, well spotted. An important point. The necessary commands were found in VB, hence this code is a VBScript Script File (.vbs)